# Is It an obligation having a company in order to have access Instagram Live API for public scope?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am developing an app which needs `public_content` scope of Live API and aware of new regulations of Instagram. After I complete my app, I will send it to Instagram for review. Issue that I wonder was, Is having a company is strictly required in order to have Live API permission ? Because I saw in documents that developers should show their apps' privacy policy and kind of stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you require to have a registered company, but your app/website should look serious and should solve a problem for brands/businesses as mentioned in the 3 approved use case by Instagram.

I used to have http://gramfeed.com for last 5 years and recently had to rename to https://www.picodash.com and refocus the service for more specific audience to get approval. It has to look professional and should NOT be a generic service to all users.

Comment: Thanks a lot @krisrak 
I'll pay attention what you mention.